# htaccess redirect won't work if file doesn't exist

Tags: apache, .htaccess, apache2, debian

Server: Debian with apache2;

var/www: 
project -> /samba/project/

samba/project:
index.php
.htaccess
test.php

htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /project/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index.php.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [L]
```

---

localhost/ -> it works

localhost/index.php -> it works

localhost/test.php -> it works (redirect to index.php works)

http://localhost/asdsads -> doesn't work (error 403)

why?

thx

Comment: Error log says that : " Symbolic link not allowed or link target not accesible " but the www-data has permissions

Answer (score 3):

Try changing your last two lines to

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-s
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

The first line checks if the requested URL does not map to a physical file, and the second line rewrites every request (which always has a beginning, denoted by ^) to index.php.

Comment: thx all we solved, there was some issue with the folder sharing between windows and debian